# Reading codelines from dataadapter generated code

Tags: .net, vb.net

In one of my project I have the following lines:

```
Me.SqlDeleteCommand1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [CLASS] WHERE (([MAIN FACILITY USED] = @Original_MAIN_FACILITY_USED) " & _
    "AND ([START DATE] = @Original_START_DATE) AND ([CentreId] = @Original_CentreId) " & _
    "AND ([RowVer] = @Original_RowVer))"
Me.SqlDeleteCommand1.Connection = Me.SqlConnection1
Me.SqlDeleteCommand1.Parameters.AddRange(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() {New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_MAIN_FACILITY_USED", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "MAIN FACILITY USED", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_START_DATE", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "START DATE", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_CentreId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "CentreId", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_RowVer", System.Data.SqlDbType.Timestamp, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "RowVer", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing)})
```

The thing is that in another project I want to read the line:

```
Me.SqlDeleteCommand1.Parameters.AddRange(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() {New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_MAIN_FACILITY_USED", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "MAIN FACILITY USED", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_START_DATE", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "START DATE", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_CentreId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "CentreId", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing), New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_RowVer", System.Data.SqlDbType.Timestamp, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "RowVer", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing)})
```

After refering to its assembly I write the following lines:

da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.ToString()

da is the dataadapter that is added so it can acces that assembly and read data from it. However the following line of code works As i wish but the upper one won't.

```
da.UpdateCommand.CommandText
```

is there any other solutions? Reading the line containing range of parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Parameters object in the DataAdapter is a SqlParameterCollection object. If you're looking for all the values/types, you can iterate through the items in that collection and get the values you need. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx) to find the values you need